# Crontab scheduling won't run(no errors)

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to make a python script(that I know works) run every 10 minutes from 9AM-6PM using cron. I'm trying this, but it won't work:

```
*/10 9-18 * * * python /home/batuhan/Downloads/InstaPy/example.py
```

I also decided to simplify things and make it run every 1 min, but that also doesn't work:

```
* * * * * python /home/batuhan/Downloads/InstaPy/example.py
```

When I do corntab -l it does list it:

```
crontab -l
* * * * * python /home/batuhan/Downloads/InstaPy/example.py
```

I also saw that you had to make it executable with chmod so I did that:

```
chmod +x /home/batuhan/Downloads/InstaPy/example.py
```

I also have the shebang line at the start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
```

There are no errors, it just doesn't run.

Edit:

```
    root@batuhan-VirtualBox:~# /etc/init.d/cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-09-21 14:36:58 EDT; 5min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 2045 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           ├─2045 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           ├─2323 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
           ├─2326 /bin/sh -c python /home/batuhan/Downloads/InstaPy/example.p...
           ├─2328 python /home/batuhan/Downloads/InstaPy/example.py
           └─2333 /usr/bin/chromedriver --port=50955

Sep 21 14:40:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2215]: (batuhan) CMD (python /home/b...)
Sep 21 14:41:01 batuhan-VirtualBox cron[2045]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Sep 21 14:41:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2271]: pam_unix(cron:session): sessi...)
Sep 21 14:41:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2270]: pam_unix(cron:session): sessi...)
Sep 21 14:41:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2272]: (root) CMD (python /home/batu...)
Sep 21 14:41:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2274]: (batuhan) CMD (python /home/b...)
Sep 21 14:42:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2324]: pam_unix(cron:session): sessi...)
Sep 21 14:42:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2323]: pam_unix(cron:session): sessi...)
Sep 21 14:42:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2325]: (root) CMD (python /home/batu...)
Sep 21 14:42:01 batuhan-VirtualBox CRON[2326]: (batuhan) CMD (python /home/b...)
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: How do you know that there are no errors? Is the cron daemon running?

Comment: I'm not sure there aren't any errors, its just that I don't see any. I think the cron daemon is running(check edit).

Comment: @BatuhanUslues: well the edit shows that it *is* running. The process has PID 2328.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the shebang from `#!/usr/bin/env/python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

`/usr/bin/env/python` is not a valid path on most Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: How do you know the script isn't running?

Comment: I tried following a guide(http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/using_cron_basics.htm) in order to see if cron was working. My command looks like this: `* * * * * echo "Hello" >>$HOME/junk.txt` but nothing is posted in the junk.txt file at home

Comment: Try writing to the `/tmp` directory instead, i.e. `/tmp/junk.txt`. The `$HOME` env var might be set to something different within the cron's context